# Dplyr - Get Running average per entity based on a filter

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, average

dput of the input dataframe :

```
structure(list(Entity = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"
), Date = structure(c(1640995200, 1641081600, 1641168000, 1641254400, 
1641340800, 1641427200, 1641513600, 1641600000, 1641686400, 1641772800, 
1640995200, 1641081600, 1641168000, 1641254400, 1641340800, 1641427200, 
1641513600, 1641600000, 1641686400, 1641772800), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Test = c("Y", "Y", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", 
"Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y"), 
    Value = c(5, 10, 5, 10, 10, 5, 5, 5, 5, 20, 10, 10, 5, 20, 
    20, 5, 5, 20, 20, 20), COUNTER = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
    7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

I would like to get a final `dataframe` that shows `running 3 day average` per entity where `Test = 'Y'`. For ex., based on the below screenshot,

[image]

the running averages for the entity A would be:

```
Entity   Counter_Running_avg     Running_Avg

A         1                     7.5 (15/2)

A         2                     10 (10/1)

A         3                     5   (15/3)    and so on..
```

I began by writing the below code but this is not what I need...

```
dt %>%      
   arrange(Entity, Date) %>%
   group_by(Entity) %>%
   filter(Test = 'Y') %>%       
   summarise(Avg = mean(head(Value, 3), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df %>%
  group_by(Entity,id = (COUNTER - 1) %/%3 + 1) %>%
  summarise(Running_Avg = mean(Value[Test == 'Y']), .groups = 'drop')
  

# Groups:   Entity [2]
  Entity    id Running_Avg
  <chr>  <dbl>       <dbl>
1 A          1         7.5
2 A          2        10  
3 A          3         5  
4 A          4        20  
5 B          1        10  
6 B          2        20  
7 B          3        15  
8 B          4        20
```

Comment: this is great. What does .groups='drop' do? @onyambu

Comment: @CodeMaster it just ensures the result is not a grouped df. You can get rid of it. or simply use `%>%ungroup()`

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Entity) %>%
  mutate(id = rep(1:n(), each = 3, length.out = n())) %>%
  group_by(Entity, id) %>%
  summarize(Avg = mean(Value[Test == "Y"]), .groups = "drop")
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
  Entity    id   Avg
  <chr>  <int> <dbl>
1 A          1   7.5
2 A          2  10  
3 A          3   5  
4 A          4  20  
5 B          1  10  
6 B          2  20  
7 B          3  15  
8 B          4  20
```

So we first create a helper id which groups your data into chunks of 3, and then we simply take the mean of value for all Test == "Y" values.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using lag and lead. These let you access values from the previous or the next row.

Start with something like:

```r
step1 = dt %>%
  group_by(Entity) %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  mutate(prev_value = lag(Value),
         prev_test = lag(Test),
         next_value = lead(Value),
         next_test = lead(Test))
```

You can then calculate the mean using each row. Something like:

```r
step2 = step1 %>%
  mutate(total = ifelse(Test == 'N', 0, Value)
               + ifelse(lag_test == 'N', 0, lag_value)
               + ifelse(lead_test == 'N', 0, lead_value),
         obs = ifelse(Test == 'N', 0, 1)
             + ifelse(lag_test == 'N', 0, 1)
             + ifelse(lead_test == 'N', 0, 1),
         avg = total / obs)
```